# Moving a layer to a group layer by its index in QGIS 3.0

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I try to use this code from QGIS 2.x version in QGIS 3.0:

```
li = iface.legendInterface()
li.moveLayer(demLayer, self.watershedGroupIndex
```

I found `QgsLayerTreeLayer` but can not use it. I want to move existing layer on layers panel by using gruop index, because I have layer and group index. However examples show me, adding map layer like that:

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(demLayer, False)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup(index.name())
group.insertChildNode(0, QgsLayerTreeLayer(myClone))
```

But I already loaded layer just want to move it to group by using its index.

Comment: What does 'index' mean in your question? Group layer order or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

[`findGroup`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeGroup.html#a24079a54dc415727b6aa05b4f4260f26) finds group node by its name not by index. You already know index, so, you get group layer by `root.children()[index].`

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

myClone= demLayer.clone()
group = root.children()[index] # index: group layer index
group.insertChildNode(0, QgsLayerTreeLayer(myClone))

# EDIT:
# after that, two layers are different although they have same source and style
demLayer == myClone  # is False


root.removeLayer(demLayer)
```

For more information: [QGIS Layer Tree API (Part 2)](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/25/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-2/)

> Moving a node(group or layer) is done in three steps: 1. clone the existing node, 2. add the cloned node to the desired place in layer tree, 3. remove the original node.

Comment: My layer has already uploaded I just want to move it to group. Your suggestion is adding map by defining false. However I have already loaded my layer

Comment: What I understand is that you have `demLayer` and a grup layer that you know its index, and you want to move `demLayer` to that group layer. Right?

Comment: Yes but this dem layer is not in folder or etc. It is uploaded already. I do not need to give path.

Comment: OK. I editted the answer. I guess, there is no way of moving a layer directly in QGIS3.

Comment: Can I email you?

Comment: It does not remove raster layer for removeChildNode

Comment: Then, try `root.removeLayer(demLayer)`

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz:
Your link 
`For more information: QGIS Layer Tree API (Part 2)`
is pointing to a resource for QGIS2. Is there an update to the link?

Comment: "*Can I email you?*" Bu mesajını yeni farkediyorum inan ki.